# sbt not generating bin directory when staging or publishing docker + other questions

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, docker-machine

I have an immediate problem as described in the title, which is that `sbt` is not generating the `bin` directory (the one that the `ENTRYPOINT` script is pointed to) when I run `docker:stage` or `docker:publishLocal`.

I have never seen this behavior before so I am a bit lost as to how to proceed, but I should also mention that I have set up this project in a different manner than I usually have.

The project is set up as follows, under its root directory:

```
- infrastructure
 - app
  - build.sbt
  - target/...
 - another-project
- project
 - BuildDefinition.scala
 - plugins.sbt
 - build.properties
- build.sbt
```

In my root `BuildDefinition.scala` I have set up all of my project definitions, including the `app` project that is not staging all I need.

In the `build.sbt` on the root, I have merely:

```
sourcesInBase in ThisBuild := false

name := "fantasy-factory"
```

In the build.sbt on the `app` directory, I have **only the Docker-related stuff**:

```
dockerBaseImage in Docker := "java:8-jre"
mainClass := Some("akka.Main")
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq("com.nv.microservice.as.cluster.ClusterEntryPoint")
version in Docker := "latest"
packageName in Docker := "basic-distributed-microservice"
```

What *does* get generated upon staging is ALMOST everything I need... everything EXCEPT the `bin` directory that has the entry point script. So I do see underneath the `app`'s `target` directory:

```
- target
 - docker
  - stage
   - opt
    - docker
     - conf
     - lib
     - (I would have expected to see bin here)
   - Dockerfile
 - Dockerfile
```

This is all quite frustrating for me; any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have same behavior and i don't understand why this happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue I solved adding `in (Compile)` to the mainClass key, as below. In your `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
.enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
.enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
.settings(
  name := "my-project",
  mainClass in (Compile) := Some("MyFQNMainClass"),
  version := "1.0.0.BUILD",
  dockerBaseImage := "azul/zulu-openjdk:8",
  dockerUpdateLatest := true,
  dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080),
  dockerRepository := Some("myrepo")
)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

sbtVersion := "0.13.9"

...
```

I also have the `plugins.sbt` file (under the `project` folder):

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "0.13.9"

addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "2.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-s3" % "0.8")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.4")

addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.8.0")
```

And `build.properties` in the same folder as `plugins.sbt`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, missed mainClass and JavaServerAppPackaging